# UWP AudioGraph : Garbage Collector causes clicks in the audio output

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

I have a C# UWP application that uses the AudioGraph API.

I use a custom effect on a `MediaSourceAudioInputNode`.

I followed the sample on this page :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-audio-effects

It works but I can hear multiple clicks per second in the speakers when the custom effect is running.

Here is the code for my `ProcessFrame` method :

```
    public unsafe void ProcessFrame(ProcessAudioFrameContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        AudioFrame frame = context.InputFrame;

        using (AudioBuffer inputBuffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Read))
        using (IMemoryBufferReference inputReference = inputBuffer.CreateReference())
        {
            ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)inputReference).GetBuffer(out byte* inputDataInBytes, out uint inputCapacity);
            Span<float> samples = new Span<float>(inputDataInBytes, (int)inputCapacity / sizeof(float));

            for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; i++)
            {
                float sample = samples[i];

                // sample processing...

                samples[i] = sample;
            }
        }
    }
```

I used the Visual Studio profiler to identify the cause of the problem.
It is clear that there is a memory problem. The garbage collection runs several times each second. At each garbage collection, I can hear a click.

The Visual Studio profiler shows that the garbage-collected objects are type `ProcessAudioFrameContext`.

These objects are created by the AudioGraph API before entering the `ProcessFrame` method and passed as a parameter to the method.

Is there something that I can do to avoid these frequent garbage collections ?

Comment: Maybe the real problem is that garbage collections pause the `AudioGraph` thread :
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/15673041--bug-audiograph-gaps-and-clicks-during-playback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not specific to custom effects, but it is a general problem with AudioGraph (current SDK is 1809).
Garbage collections can pause the AudioGraph thread for a too long time (more than 10ms, it is the default size of audio buffers). The result is that clicks can be heard in the audio output.
The use of custom effects puts a lot of pressure on the garbage collector.

I found a good workaround. It uses the `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` method.

After this method is called, the clicks completely disappear. But the app keeps growing in memory until the `GC.EndNoGCRegion` method is called.

```
// at the beginning of playback...
// 240 Mb is the amount of memory that can be allocated before a GC occurs
GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(240 * 1024 * 1024, true);

// ... at the end of playback
GC.EndNoGCRegion();
```

MSDN doc :
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?view=netframework-4.7.2

And a good article :
https://mattwarren.org/2016/08/16/Preventing-dotNET-Garbage-Collections-with-the-TryStartNoGCRegion-API/

Answer (score 0):

the garbage collector is probably reacting to you initializing the sample temporary memory every frame, which is then released after the frame, try assign the memory for holding the samples in your start up code and just reuse it every frame.

Comment: The problem is that I can't do that (or I don't know how do do it). The AudioGraph API creates the ProcessAudioFrameContext for me. I would be glad to reuse the AudioFrame object. But I can't find any sample code other than the official one...

Comment: I was talking about the GC of the span<float> samples= new .. this creates the memory and when your frame has finished GC has to clean it.

Comment: To my understanding of Span<T>, it is a typed view over unmanaged memory (the byte* inputDataInBytes). It is allocated on the stack. So it has no impact on garbage collection. I had the problem before usin Span...